# Is it possible make a Pass-The-Hash attack with Responder?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, ntlm, domain-controller, pass-the-hash

The tool [Responder](https://github.com/lgandx/Responder) written in Python permits to listen on a specific network card requests and automatically poisoning victims the steal hash `NTLMv1` and hash `NTLMv2`.

The attack [Pass-The-Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash) permits to connect to a service like SMB.
I am a little bit confused about difference between hash `LM` and hash `NTLM` and so the consequences of a Pass-The-Hash attack.
I know that it's also possible to crack the hash `NTLMv1` or `NTLMv2` with John for example.

From the premise that password is complex and it's not possible to brute-force it, apart connect to a share and get some sensitive files :

1. What can do an attacker on the same network ?
2. Is it possible to forge connect to RDP service for example ?
3. Is it possible to forge a sliver/gold Kerberos ticket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responder gathers `NetNTLMv1` and `NetNTLMv2` hashes, to be precise. These hashes are generated as part of a challenge-response mechanism, and as a result in much harder to crack than `LM` or `NTLM` hashes, which are based on a not-so-strong encryption algorithm.

1. An attacker running Responder inside a network can use a tool such as [NTLMRelayx](https://github.com/SecureAuthCorp/impacket/blob/master/examples/ntlmrelayx.py) from impacket to relay the credentials to any SMB server which has [SMB Signing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/887429/overview-of-server-message-block-signing) disabled. Note that the attacker cannot relay these credentials back to the service on the same system from where the hashes were captured.
2. Although an attacker cannot RDP to a server using relaying, they should still be able to gain administrative access to the server through SMB (provided the credentials relayed belonged to a privileged user)
3. No, an attacker cannot forge golden/silver ticket using just the `NetNTLMvx` hashes.